# Text in the EditText Disappears

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout of 14 rows and each row is having 2 EditText Fields. I have button which the user clicks and the program computes and prints the answer. The problem is as soon as the user clicks the button the character entered in last EditText field disappears but when the user clicks on it it reappers. Please help me to solve this problem. Here is the xml file.

```
 <TableRow 
 android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="50dp">

 <TextView 
 android:textSize="20sp" 
 android:typeface="sans" 
 android:textStyle="bold" 
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:id="@+id/sub1" 
 android:padding="10dp" 
 android:layout_width="120dp" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="@string/sub1" />

 <EditText 
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:id="@+id/subject1" 
 android:padding="10dp" 
 android:layout_width="120dp" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:inputType="text" >
 <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <EditText 
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:id="@+id/credits1" 
 android:padding="10dp" 
 android:layout_width="120dp" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:inputType="phone" >
 <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 </TableRow>
```

Here is on click code

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setText("");
            num=0;
            den=0;
            f=0;

            if(dept.equalsIgnoreCase("cse")||dept.equalsIgnoreCase("mechtronics")||dept.equalsIgnoreCase("genetics")) {
                for(int i=0;i<12;i++) {
                    s[i]=sub[i].getText().toString();
                    g[i]=SetGP.setGP(s[i]);
                    c[i]=Float.parseFloat(cre[i].getText().toString());
                    if((g[i]==-1)&&((c[i]>=1)&&(c[i]<=4))) {
                        j=String.valueOf(i+1);
                        Toast.makeText(Gpa.this, "Please Enter Valid Grade For Subject "+j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        f=1;
                        break;
                    }   
                    else if((g[i]!=-1)&&((c[i]<1)||(c[i]>4))) {
                        j=String.valueOf(i+1);
                        Toast.makeText(Gpa.this, "Please Enter Valid Credits For Subject "+j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        f=1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if((g[i]==-1)&&((c[i]<1)||(c[i]>4))) {
                        j=String.valueOf(i+1);
                        Toast.makeText(Gpa.this, "Please Enter Valid Grade and Credits For Subject "+j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        f=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
                    num = CalcGPA.calcnum(g[i], c[i], num);
                    den = CalcGPA.calcden(c[i], den);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Show your button click event code.

Comment: @PiyushGupta See the post now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it I just changed from **RelativeLayout** To **LinearLayout** That there solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick has a reference to a global TextView variable ("tv") which it sets to ("") an empty String.  Is this perhaps the reason the text in one of your views is disappearing when you click the button?

I realize your problem is the last view changing which appears to be an editText, but an editText is castable to TextView so it's something to check.

Comment: Ok so what should i do?

Comment: Need you to determine if any of your Views are legitimately being blanked out, and if so, is the correct one being blanked.

Comment: Don't get angry but I don't follow you legimately blanked? and what do you mean by the correct one?

Comment: Your code removes the text from one of the textViews with tv.setText("");  Your problem is also that one of the textViews is losing its text when you click the button that executes that code.  So, obviously, we need to figure out if the two things are related.  Is your code supposed to be removing the text from any of the TextViews when you click that button (i.e. are they being legitimately blanked)?  If so, is it blanking the correct TextView?

Comment: Ok since you said its clashing i removed the tv.setText("") and after that I clicked the button it doesn't disappear but now when i scroll up it disappears...

Comment: unfortunately from the code provided, i can't really tell you why any of the editText would get blanked when you scroll.

Comment: java file:- http://pastebin.com/utRMQ60B xml file:- http://pastebin.com/G01TcXN1 hope you can point where i made a mistake.